# Make button as circle icon

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a profile icon which will used as dropdown. I tried this:

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return <button className="profile">Profile</button>;
}
```

**styles**

```
.profile {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1888ff;
}

.profile:hover {
  padding: 6px 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #1888ff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Do you know how I can make the button as a circle with dropdown?

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-shamir-osu68

Comment: Please share code here in a code snippet and be more clear of what you want to achieve. If you just want a circle why don't you use a bigger border-radius ?

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow css selectors to `profile` button:

```
.profile {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

[image: Edit jovial-bas-nbyx4]